# How can I combine these two SQL queries into a single query?

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, inner-join

I am using the Sakila database within MySql 5.6.25.

The first query gives me the films which are providing our "store" with the highest revenue in descending order. I also show the times it has been rented  and it's rental rate:

```
SELECT f.title, f.rental_rate, count(r.rental_id) AS "Times Rented", count(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate as Revenue
    from film f 
    INNER JOIN inventory i
       ON f.film_id = i.film_id
    INNER JOIN rental r
        ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    GROUP BY f.title
    ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

The second query is showing us how many copies of the film we have on hand:

```
SELECT film.title, count(inventory.film_id)
from film
INNER JOIN inventory
ON film.film_id = inventory.film_id
group by film.title
```

I understand how both queries are working... independently... but when I try to combine them, they produce unexpected results. Please show me the correct way to combine them without changing the manner in which results are being shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those unaware, mysql comes with a great practice database call **sakila** on which to practice queries.

### correct approach (or something like it)

```
SELECT f.title, 
f.rental_rate, 
count(r.rental_id) AS "Times Rented", 
count(r.rental_id) * f.rental_rate as Revenue,
(select count(*) from inventory where film_id=f.film_id) as InvCount
    from film f 
    INNER JOIN inventory i
       ON f.film_id = i.film_id
    INNER JOIN rental r
        ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    GROUP BY f.title
    ORDER BY revenue DESC
```

This will give you InvCount=8 for first row (film BUCKET BROTHERHOOD).

### wrong approach

```
count(i.film_id) as InvCount
```

is because `alias i` is driven by its last join on alias `rental r` in the whole query.

So for the first row of output, BUCKET BROTHERHOOD, with 34 rentals and 8 actual inventory of the item ....

If you do it the wrong way it shows InvCount=34. The correct answer is 8.

Always do a sanity check with the data to keep the boss from yelling at you.

```
select film_id,title from film where title like 'bucket br%'; -- film_id=103

select count(*) from inventory where film_id=103; -- count=8
```